# Drupal Alignment screwed up in IE but works great in FF

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drupal

I have designed a site for my team using drupal and it works and looks great in FF but when i open it in IE the page looks as if it is murdered by someone. The alignment is screwed up totally. What can i do to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an IE style sheet and include it using conditional styles:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  add stylesheet here.
<![endif]-->
```

If you are using a subtheme of zen, you can use conditional styles in your `.info` file:

```
conditional-stylesheets[if IE][all][] = css/ie.css
```

**Update:**
You also need to remember to compress your css files, since Drupal usually will use more css files than IE can handle with css optimization is disabled. This in turn, will require you to clear the cache a lot.

Comment: The images are scattered all over the page, text appears big, links appear broken. It's 1 helluva mess. In my homepage there are data which are included from 3 or 4 different pages and each one has there own style sheet. I am just stuck and don't know what to do. In FF everything is hunky dory but this IE is causing lot of problems. I tired many different things but everytime when one problem is fixed another problem arises.

Comment: You should also know that there are large differences between versions of IE. IE6 is so difficult and so old that many people no longer support it even though there are still many users on it. IE7 poses it's own set of problems (e.g., float bugs, lack of inline-block, etc.). IE8 is relatively well behaved. I always check on Safari as well. Sometimes the problem is programmer error too.